# ¿Dónde configurar el wildcard cuando tengo varios módulos cada uno con su módulo routing?

Tags: angular

Estoy haciendo un proyecto de prueba en Angular que tiene la siguiente estructura:

- Error (error.component.ts)
- Home (home.module.ts, home.component.ts y home-routing.module.ts)
- Saludo (saludo.module.ts, saludo.component.ts y saludo-routing.module.ts)

En el app-routing.module.ts tengo lo siguiente:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
];
```

En el home-routing.module.ts tengo lo siguiente:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
];
```

Y en el saludo-routing.module.ts tengo lo siguiente:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'saludo', component: SaludoComponent }
];
```

En el app.component.ts tengo el siguiente código para navegar a esos componentes:

```
<nav>
  <a routerLink="/home" routerLinkActive="linkActivo">Home</a>
  <a routerLink="/saludo" routerLinkActive="linkActivo">Saludo</a>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Y por último, en el app.module.ts tengo lo siguiente:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeModule } from './home/home.module';
import { SaludoModule } from './saludo/saludo.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HomeModule,
    SaludoModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Hasta aquí todo funciona correctamente.
El problema es que no sé dónde poner el wildcard para cuando escriban una dirección que no existe. Si pongo en el app-routing.module.ts lo siguiente:

```
{ path: '**', component: ErrorComponent }
```

Da igual la ruta que le ponga, que todas me llevan a la página de error, y yo sólo quiero que me lleve a esa cuando ninguno de sus módulos sea capaz de resolver sus respectivas rutas.

¿Cómo configuro esto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

creo que deberías implementar `lazyload` para que te funcione ok, te muestro como lo haría.

En el `app-routing.module.ts` colocaria lo siguiente:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then((m) => m.HomeModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'saludo',
    loadChildren: () => import('./saludo/saludo.module').then((m) => m.SaludoModule),
  },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', component: ErrorComponent },
];
```

En el `home-routing.module.ts`

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', 
     component: HomeComponent,
     children:[
        {path: 'paginaX', component: PaginaXComponent}    
     ]
  },
  {path:'', redirecTo: HomeComponent}
 ];
```

En el `saludo-routing.module.ts`

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: SaludoComponent ];
```

Comment: Pero aunque utilices lazy load estás definiendo todas las rutas en el app-routing.module.ts. Si el proyecto fuera enorme no tendría mucho sentido definir todo ahí, no? No hay una forma de que cada módulo defina sus propias rutas y de alguna forma definir la página 404?

Comment: Todas las rutas no se definen en `app-routing.module.ts` que si tienes rutas que dependen por ejemplo del `home-routing.module.ts` estas se declararían aquí y en tu aplicación tendrás una ruta así `http://127.0.0.1:4200/home/paginaX`, voy a modificarte la respuesta.